# Analog pins showing incorrect data. Only from 0 to 255

Tags: arduino, analog, error, arduino-uno, read

A month ago, I connected a joystick with an Arduino Uno. VCC with Arduino 5v, GND with ground and Y axis with analog. I tried all, but the error persist with all 6.

A month ago, in the serial monitor I got data ranging from 0 to 1023. Today, when I retry it, something strange happens. In the center position it shows 255. As I move my joystick forward, the pattern goes like this 255 0... 50...200... 255... 0.. 50... 150.... and stops at 255. When I pull it back same happens, 255... 200... 150... 100... 0 255... 100.. 50... and stops at 0.

I don't understand why it changed. It was kept in a plastic box under normal conditions, and now the analog pins give incorrect data.

I tried the joystick with another Arduino, and I get the right data, but I want to know what the problem is, if I can fix it, how to, why it happens and how to prevent it.

PS: I didn't change any wiring or give extra voltage or did some stuff that could damage my Arduino. All other parts work fine.

Can you tell me what mistake I might be making?

```
#include<SPI.h>


void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A3, INPUT); // I tried with this line and without this line too. Same results
                                                                                                                                        
}
void loop() {
  
  y1 = analogRead(4);
  y2 = analogRead(5);
  Serial.println(y1);
  Serial.println(y2);
    
  delay(50);
  
}
```

Comment: Did you recompile the code between now and when it previously worked?

Comment: No, I didn't recompile, yet I got a different result. But then I recompiled and tried again yet it didn't work

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem, but just in case, can you post your full code? Or at least the declaration/type of y1 and y2.

Comment: The mistake does not show because type of y1 and y2 is not shown.

Comment: You might want to check if RN4B is solidly soldered and working, or if IO1 is externally loaded down.